# Prove that the rings $\frac{\Bbb F_3[X]}{(X^3+X^2+2)}$ and $\frac{\Bbb F_3[X]}{(X^3+2X+2)}$ are isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, ring-isomorphism

> Prove that the rings $\frac{\Bbb F_3[X]}{(X^3+X^2+2)}$ and $\frac{\Bbb F_3[X]}{(X^3+2X+2)}$ are isomorphic.

I tried to construct an explicit isomorphism using a similar technique as used in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1096866/943723) and arrived at the fact that if $\tau$ is one such isomorphism from $\frac{\Bbb F_3[X]}{(X^3+2X+2)}$ to $\frac{\Bbb F_3[X]}{(X^3+X^2+2)}$, then $\tau(\beta)=1+\alpha+\alpha^2$.

But, now I am confused about how to prove that it will indeed generate an isomorphism. I am pretty sure, it's not much, but I can't figure out how.

Comment: Did you try the 27 elements to find a root of $X^3+2X+2$ in $\Bbb{F}_3[y]/(y^3+y^2+2)$

Comment: @reuns Isn't the method I linked to, precisely doing that?

Comment: Not really ${}{}{}$

Comment: @reuns do you mean I explicitly calculate for all the 27 elements? I can't see how that's a possibility. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Sure, with $f(X)=X^3+2X+2$ you'll compute $f(a+by+cy^2)$ for each $a,b,c\in 0\ldots 2$ and $y$ the one of $\Bbb{F}_3[y]/(y^3+y^2+2)$

Comment: @reuns thanks to your comment, I realised that I was doing something wrong in my previous attempt. Now, I finally got (using the same technique I linked) that if $\tau$ is one such isomorphism, then $\tau(\beta)=1+\alpha+\alpha^2$. But, now I am confused about how to prove that it will indeed generate an isomorphism. I am pretty sure, it's not much, but I can't figure out how.

Comment: Both are fields with 27 elements (the cubics have no root in $\Bbb{F}_3$) so an homomorphism is automatically injective and surjective. Alternatively you can find the inverse isomorphism (ie. which element is mapped to $y$)

Comment: @reuns thanks, got it!